# SCardEstablishContext returns 1753 (EPT_S_NOT_REGISTERED) on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, visual-c++, smartcard, winscard

I'm using the Windows SCard (Winscard.h) API in a user space application to interact with a smart card reader. The application works fine on a Windows 10 Enterprise computer which is also joined to a domain but not on a Windows 10 Home computer which is not joined to any domain (this is not possible with such version).

The function is called in this way:

```
result = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER, NULL, NULL, &pcontext);
```

The **result** variable contains the value 1753 (EPT_S_NOT_REGISTERED) and I don't understand what "There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper." does mean in the smart card context. 
The following questions arise

1. Does Windows 10 Home support smart card API ?
2. Is it required the computer to join a domain in order to use such API ?

Comment: this is rpc error. some remote call fail. faster of all service (*SCardSvr*) not started

Comment: Thanks @RbMm but the mentioned service is already running. I tried to start ScDeviceEnum but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by upgrading to the Windows 10 version 1803 using the Windows update application. The previous version was something like 17xx.

I tried also activating the OS by using a Home product key but it was not enough.
So probably it was a misconfiguration or a known bug fixed with the upgrade.

The event log doesn't show anything useful. I thought that the problem was caused by the error "Event 10016, DistributedCOM" but this is not disappeared with the upgrade (the error keep appearing in the log) and the application is working now so it was not related to the problem.